# Drastic increase in outgoing bandwidth

Tags: bandwidth-control

My Outgoing Bandwidth has increased dramatically over last 6 months.

Our setup is Windows web-server and MSSQL Database server.

To give you an example the outgoing bandwidth of my web-server in September was 485.702 GB but now in April it was 1,137.765 GB

Same with database. In September it was 0.698 GB and in April it was 2,299.599 GB.

I have literally no idea from where to start? Is there any tool to have a look at which can help in monitoring.

I have tested all the websites on our webserver, and they are all GZIPPED in IIS.

Any advice will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Have you had a 3 fold increase in visitors ?

Comment: No that is the whole concern here. Our visitor count is pretty much the same.

Answer (score 0):

Start by opening Resource Manager / Task Manager, and see what files get accessed / what processes are running / which processes use bandwith.

Once you have identified the process using bandwith or the files that get served, you can dig deeper into them